# Create tex files with Python with proper indentation

Tags: python, latex

I am using Python to create the `tex` file for some of my LaTeX projects. The problem is that if I want to have proper indentation in my Python code then the resulting `tex` file has awful indents because the strings keep the spaces and tabs I add in Python. How can I remedy that?

A sample of my Python code is the following:

```
import os

from pathlib import Path

import subprocess

import shutil

# ==============================================================================
#
# ==============================================================================

report_files_path = Path("./report-files")

filenames = os.listdir(report_files_path)
filenames.sort()

with open("./source-files/main.tex", "w") as file:

    file.write(
        r"""
        \documentclass{report}

        \usepackage{preamble}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{titlepage}
            
            \vspace*{\fill}

            {\Large \textbf{Book}}

            \today

            \vspace{\fill}

        \end{titlepage}

        %
        %

        \tableofcontents

        %
        %
        """
    )

    for filename in filenames:

        if ".tex" in filename:

            file.write("\n")
            file.write(f"\input{{../{Path(report_files_path, filename)}}}")
            file.write("\n\n")

    file.write(
        r"""
        %
        %
        """
    )

    file.write("\n")
    file.write("\end{document}")

# ==============================================================================
#
# ==============================================================================

command = (
    r"""
        cd source-files && \
        latexmk \
            -quiet \
            -outdir=../output-files \
            -shell-escape \
            main.tex
    """
)

subprocess.run(command, shell = True)

shutil.copyfile(
    "output-files/main.pdf",
    "./book.pdf"
)
```

The resulting 'tex` file is the following:

```
        \documentclass{report}

        \usepackage{preamble}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{titlepage}
            
            \vspace*{\fill}

            {\Large \textbf{Book}}

            \today

            \vspace{\fill}

        \end{titlepage}

        %
        %

        \tableofcontents

        %
        %
        
\input{../report-files/report_1.tex}


\input{../report-files/report_2.tex}

        %
        %
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could run `latexindent` on the finished .tex files?